# Improving MySQL Query: Count rows

Tags: php, mysql, select, count

I have the following query where it takes minutes to load, when actually I need only to count how many rows it returns. I would like to know if is it possible to improve this query?

```
SELECT (clock - clock mod 300) as time, avg(value) as value FROM table.history_uint WHERE itemid = 82660 AND clock >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('".$date."') AND clock <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('".$date."') GROUP BY time;
```

This is my code:

```
$queryPageInfo = "SELECT (clock - clock mod 300) as time, avg(value) as value FROM table.history_uint WHERE itemid = 82660 AND clock >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('".$date."') AND clock <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('".$date."') GROUP BY time";
$resultPageInfo = $mysqli->query($queryPageInfo);
$qtd = $resultPageInfo->num_rows;
```

Comment: I would just mention that your two clock conditions appear to break down to `clock == UNIX_TIMESTAMP($date)`. In general if `A >= B` and `A <= B` then  `A==B`.

Comment: @Don'tPanic It can't be "greater than or equal to or less than or equal" it must be "greater than or equal to AND less than or equal" (i.e. equal in this context)

Comment: do `select count(*) from ...` instead, then, if you don't care about the actual content of the rows. don't make the DB retrieve data from disk that you're just going to ignore anyways.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Unfortunately I made a mistake, there were $date1 and date2. I had to translate everything to get easier to understand, but I wrote both variables as the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT clock DIV 300)
FROM table.history_uint 
WHERE itemid = 82660 AND clock = UNIX_TIMESTAMP('".$date."')
;
```

`(clock - clock mod 300)` should be the same value as `clock div 300`, but likely with less overhead; mod ops typically some of the more expensive operations, since they are usually implemented as x-(x*(x div y)). Since you only want the number of rows returned, you only need the number of values that would've been grouped on; hence the `COUNT(DISTINCT)`; and as @ssnobody pointed out above, x <= y && x >= y indicates x==y.

Comment: To further improve performance, an index `ON history_uint(itemid,clock)` would be a covering index for the query. (The query could be satisfied entirely from the index, without any lookups of pages in the underlying table.) We'd want the `itemid` column first, because of the equality predicate. We'd expect MySQL to do a range scan operation on the index.